# Google Chrome Microphone problems. No joy whatever the settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been getting annoyed from this. It was used to work fine, but it must have happened with some recent update.
I'm on Google Chrome 71 and the microphone doesn't work. Regardless the extension (including Google Meet) and the settings which clearly shows the microphone as active, the audio is not passing sounds in.
The audio settings at computer level are fine, the chrome settings are fine and the microphone is enabled and whitelisted for the given site.

I tried also to fully reset the browser, restoring to the original settings and to use unlinking my accounts. No joy.

Conversely, while using Chromoium (Google Canary) everything works fine.

Has anybody experiencing the same or found a solution?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. See if it's reported/fixed on https://crbug.com or report it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in a nutshell - and after having reported this to their chrome bug center - it turned out to be an issue I (and very likely many other users) have been experiencing with the upgrade to MoJave.

Basically, the upgrade seems to remove the microphone access at OS level.

To **fix/check this, go into System Preference > Security and Privacy > Microphone and re-instate the check to Google Chrome**, which should in theory unticked as it was on my case.